# What's the Third party login backend flow?

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I am new to third-party login , I use Facebook-login, and after some research, I know that

1. after front-end click on the login with facebook button and did the login ,
2. it can send info and redirect to backend API
3. and I supposed to use passport-facebook to do the authentication,
4. if it pass , then we check if the user exists or not , if not then create a user
5. if exists then we can return some info (maybe jwt to the User for rest of the action)

So my first question is that if my research is right or not ? or is there something I missed ?

and the second is that my userInfo database now has two basic database field, email and password, and those are required,

but with this third party login ,what's the right way to manage and set up the database , since I don't have any password to set and email may cause repeat since if user decided to sign up with my own member system and they already use same email with their facebook account ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your research is right.

Actually, there are two tables involved in for implementation, one is `User` table as parent while the other is `UserLogin` table as child. So everything is obvious and association between local account and external account is set up.

You can refer to this blog for more details
https://code-maze.com/external-identity-provider-aspnet-core-identity/